# add symbol to sql sum output

Tags: sql, casting, sum

I am trying to append a '$' to the begining of my sum output. Right now my output is in the form 25.00, 0.00, etc. and I would like it to be, $25.00, $0.00, etc. I realize I need to do some sort of a cast but all of the variations I have tried have caused errors.

```
select customer.customer_num, customer.fname, customer.lname, customer.city, 
    customer.state, coalesce(sum(items.total_price),0) amountSpent
from customer
    left join orders
        on customer.customer_num = orders.customer_num
    left join items
        on orders.order_num = items.order_num
        and items.manu_code like 'HRO'
group by customer.customer_num, customer.fname
```

Comment: like this `'$'+ cast (coalesce(sum(items.total_price),0) as varchar(50))`

Comment: is it mysql or oracle or ms sql?

Comment: gives error. check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(50))
from customer
    left join orders
        on customer.customer_num'

Comment: @user3192682 `Concat('$', cast (coalesce(sum(items.total_price),0) as varchar(50)) )`

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can cast the value to varchar

```
(case when sum(items.total_price) >0 
      then concat('$', cast(sum(items.total_price) as char(100)) ) 
      else '$0' end ) amountSpent
```